# Manage large font size in TextView in Android

Tags: android, fonts, textview

In normal font size layout is showing without any issues. But when user change font size from setting and make it big, whole app screen layout font become very huge so that user unable to read it.

In normal scenario

[image]

When font size changed
[image]

So here issue is I cant keep fixed font size, I have to show user selected font size. Issue is as font become bigger and bigger whole layout will stretch vertically.

I am expecting to have something like below.

[image]

So when on font enlarge we can enough space to show data.

Please help me. Can I have responsive layout so based on available space component get display accordingly.

Comment: check out [THIS](https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView) lib, but still I don't think it will resolve all your layout problems

Answer (score 0):

What about something simple like this:

```
public static final float getMeasureTextSize(float viewWidth, float viewHeight, final float scale /* 0.0F - 1.0F */, final String text)
{
    final Rect bounds = new Rect();
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextSize((Math.min(viewWidth, viewHeight) / 250F) * 150F);
    paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
    if(bounds.width() > (viewWidth * scale) || bounds.height() > (viewHeight * scale)) {
        paint.setTextSize(viewWidth);
        paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
        viewWidth = viewWidth * ((viewWidth * scale) / bounds.width());
        viewHeight = viewHeight * ((viewHeight * scale) / bounds.height());
    }
    return Math.min(viewWidth, viewHeight);
}
```

Then try it with a scale of `0.7F`.