# Font Resize using Seekbar, but text in the same string

Tags: java, android, seekbar

I am trying to create a font resizing setting for the apps. Basically, it consist of 2 line of text in a string, and 2 seekbars. i know it possible with spannablestring, but in my knowledges, it can only increase, not decrease, and also limited to short text, as we need to put the int start and end, so if it was a long string, i think it is not quite a good way. is there any ideas? i put a picture to help clearing my questions.

[image: SDSDSDSDS]

All the text are in a same string. i thinking if making the string in array will help, but i cant really think the way to solve the problems. any help ?

Comment: you can change setTextSize every time seekbar change listener is called, don't you?

Comment: yes i do, but if i manually done like that, if it was a long text, i think it might be a better way to do it, im also thinking about custom listview for now.

Comment: [Manage large font size in TextView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66099568/manage-large-font-size-in-textview-in-android/66100931#66100931)

Comment: Would you elaborate in answers section?

Comment: Actually i dont really have problems with large font, my questions is, is there any way to make long text, resizeble in desirred rows. All i can think now is to make custom listview, set 2 string array, and convert it to arraylist, and put set both in listview. Or it also can be item and subitem, but both resizeable seperately. Please help me if this ideas is ok, and explain it ive been banging my heads for 2 days for this 

Comment: @MrLearning The link I gave to you has the answer. Set the `scale` accordings to your need. eg. if your progress is between `0 - 100`, divide it by a `100`, `(50 / 100 = 0.5F)`, will give you the current progress scaling. Use the return value of that method, to set your font sizes `(setTextSize(getMeasureTextSize(..)))`.